# Python how to order Xml file according to CSV ordering?

Tags: python, pandas, xml, csv

I have this XML File:- final.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestSuite Name="DM123">
  <Group Name="TestRoot" ExecutionPolicy="AnyDeviceAnyOrder">
    <Parameters>
      <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxA" Value="1" />
      <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="MaxB" Value="120" />
      <Parameter Type="String" Name="MaxC" Value="integration" />
    </Parameters>
    <Children>
      <Test Name="Test1" Namespace="TestCases">
        <Parameters>
           <Parameter Type="Device" Name="Device">
             <Requirements>
               <Requirement TypeId="a76" Source="User" />
               <Requirement TypeId="2c9" Source="User" />
             </Requirements>
           </Parameter>
        </Parameters>
      </Test>
      <Test Name="Test5" Namespace="TestCases">
        <Parameters>
           <Parameter Type="Dev" Name="Dev">
               <Requirements>
                 <Requirement TypeId="a76" Source="User" />
                 <Requirement TypeId="2c9" Source="User" />
               </Requirements>
           </Parameter>
        </Parameters>
      </Test>
      <Test Name="Test6" Namespace="TestCases">
            <Parameters>
              <Parameter Type="Dev" Name="Dev">
                <Requirements>
                  <Requirement TypeId="a76" Source="User" />
                  <Requirement TypeId="2c9" Source="User" />
                </Requirements>
              </Parameter>
              <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="expected amount of images" Value="10" />
            </Parameters>
      </Test>
   </Children>
  </Group>
  <Models>
    <Model Name="DD1" />
  </Models>
</TestSuite>
```

The xml file contains test case names and its details. This is just a sample but i have thousands of test cases like this in a xml file.

I have a CSV file which also contains the same test cases but in a ordered way. The order is defined using some specific parameter like Shortest processing time first:-

```
Id TestName
0    Test5
1    Test1
3    Test6
```

i want to order the xml file according to the CSV file. I am a beginner in python. How can i do that in python? Thanks in advance

Desired Output:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestSuite Name="DM123">
  <Group Name="TestRoot" ExecutionPolicy="AnyDeviceAnyOrder">
    <Parameters>
      <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxA" Value="1" />
      <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="MaxB" Value="120" />
      <Parameter Type="String" Name="MaxC" Value="integration" />
    </Parameters>
    <Children>
      <Test Name="Test5" Namespace="TestCases">
        <Parameters>
           <Parameter Type="Dev" Name="Dev">
               <Requirements>
                 <Requirement TypeId="a76" Source="User" />
                 <Requirement TypeId="2c9" Source="User" />
               </Requirements>
           </Parameter>
        </Parameters>
      </Test>
      <Test Name="Test1" Namespace="TestCases">
        <Parameters>
           <Parameter Type="Device" Name="Device">
             <Requirements>
               <Requirement TypeId="a76" Source="User" />
               <Requirement TypeId="2c9" Source="User" />
             </Requirements>
           </Parameter>
        </Parameters>
      </Test>
      <Test Name="Test6" Namespace="TestCases">
            <Parameters>
              <Parameter Type="Dev" Name="Dev">
                <Requirements>
                  <Requirement TypeId="a76" Source="User" />
                  <Requirement TypeId="2c9" Source="User" />
                </Requirements>
              </Parameter>
              <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="expected amount of images" Value="10" />
            </Parameters>
      </Test>
   </Children>
  </Group>
  <Models>
    <Model Name="DD1" />
  </Models>
</TestSuite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach would be to use BeautifulSoup to help with the XML parsing. This can be installed using:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

The code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import glob


tests = {}

# Read in the XML files and parse them

for xml_filename in glob.glob('*.xml'):
    print(f'Parsing {xml_filename}')
    
    with open(xml_filename) as f_input:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f_input, 'xml')
        
    # Store all test tags in a dictionary 
    # (this assumes each test has a unique name)

    for test in soup.find_all('Test'):
        tests[test['Name']] = test

# Locate the children tag and empty it

children = soup.find('Children')
children.clear()

# Read in the ordering CSV and append the tests in the required order into
# the children tag

with open('order.csv', newline='') as f_order:
    csv_order = csv.reader(f_order)
    header = next(csv_order)
    
    for id, test_name in csv_order:
        try:
            children.append(tests.pop(test_name))
        except KeyError:
            print(f"Test '{test_name}' not present")
 
# Add any remaining tests not listed in the CSV
    
for test in tests.values():
    children.append(test)
    
# Write the modified xml

with open('output.xml', 'w') as f_output:
    f_output.write(str(soup))
```

The indenting of the XML will be modified but the structure will be maintained. A "prettier" output style can be obtained by changing the output write to:

```
f_output.write(soup.prettify())
```

It first stores all of the tests in a Python dictionary from all of the XML files. Then whilst reading your ordering CSV file it uses pop to read each test back out of the dictionary and append it into the children tag. By using `pop()` it also removes the test from the dictionary. Any tests left over in the dictionary (that were not in the ordering CSV) could then be added to the end (if needed).

Comment: I have multiple xml files how can I open each of them one by one and write them again in the same file?

Comment: You could iterate over the files using `glob.glob('*.xml')`. I assume all the test names would be unique?

Comment: I am getting error KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-162-4e0acb2a7edb> in <module>
     27 
     28     for Id, test_name in header:
---> 29         children.append(tests.pop(test_name))
     30 
     31 # Add any remaining tests not listed in the CSV

KeyError: 'd'

Comment: That would happen if the test name in `order.csv` is not present in `input.xml`. I have added an exception handling to show when this happens

Comment: It is giving me this error:- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-208-7ef10cfb792b> in <module>
     28     for TestCaseName in csv_order:
     29         try:
---> 30             children.append(tests.pop(TestCaseName))
     31         except KeyError:
     32             print(f"Test '{TestCaseName}' not present")

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: You have broken the script, the whole row is now returned as a list rather than two variables. The dictionary key needs to just be the name when `.pop()` is called

Comment: If your order file is just a single column, either add `[0]` or remove the need for a `csv.reader()` and just read as a normal file